# Replacing QKeyEvents in qApp eventFilter

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5

I'm trying to write a PyQt5 app that catches certain keystrokes and replaces them with some other keystroke.  Since I want this replacement to occur for the entire app, I understood (perhaps incorrectly) that I needed an event filter on `qApp`.  After searching around, I cobbled together this proof-of-concept:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

# Keys to block
kmap = [Qt.Key_U,Qt.Key_I,Qt.Key_O,Qt.Key_P,Qt.Key_J,Qt.Key_K,Qt.Key_L,Qt.Key_M]

class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    # The simplest UI
    def initUI(self):               
        self.edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

        QtWidgets.qApp.installEventFilter(self)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.edit)
        # Window placement 
        self.show()

    def sendkeys(self, char, modifier=Qt.NoModifier):
        event = QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, 0, modifier, char)
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.postEvent(self, event)
        event = QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyRelease, 0, modifier, char)
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.postEvent(self, event)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if type(event) == QtGui.QKeyEvent:
            print("Normal stroke %d of type %s to %s" % (event.key(), str(event.type()), str(obj)))
            if event.key() in kmap:
                if type(obj) == QtWidgets.QTextEdit and obj.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
                    sendkeys("c")
                return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  At all.

First, blocked and unblocked keys produce different events, even though I filter after logging:

```
Normal stroke 66 of type 51 to <PyQt5.QtGui.QWindow object at 0x7ff4800af948>
Normal stroke 66 of type 51 to <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTextEdit object at 0x7ff4800af8b8>
Normal stroke 66 of type 6 to <PyQt5.QtGui.QWindow object at 0x7ff4800af948>
Normal stroke 66 of type 6 to <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTextEdit object at 0x7ff4800af8b8>
Normal stroke 66 of type 7 to <PyQt5.QtGui.QWindow object at 0x7ff4800af948>
Normal stroke 66 of type 7 to <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTextEdit object at 0x7ff4800af8b8>
Normal stroke 66 of type 7 to <__main__.Example object at 0x7ff4800af828>
Normal stroke 77 of type 51 to <PyQt5.QtGui.QWindow object at 0x7ff4800af948>
Normal stroke 77 of type 6 to <PyQt5.QtGui.QWindow object at 0x7ff4800af948>
Normal stroke 77 of type 7 to <PyQt5.QtGui.QWindow object at 0x7ff4800af948>
```

Second, `sendkeys` doesn't work--the strokes just never show up.

I'm not quite sure what I'm misunderstanding--any pointers?

Comment: Did my solution work?

Comment: Yep, perfectly--just forgot to mark it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to replace the keystrokes that are sent, what you must do is send them to the same object, instead you are sending them to the window:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

# Keys to block
kmap = [Qt.Key_U,Qt.Key_I,Qt.Key_O,Qt.Key_P,Qt.Key_J,Qt.Key_K,Qt.Key_L,Qt.Key_M]

class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    # The simplest UI
    def initUI(self):               
        self.edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.edit)
        QtWidgets.qApp.installEventFilter(self)
        # Window placement 
        self.show()

    def sendkeys(self, obj, char, modifier=Qt.NoModifier):
        event = QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, 0, modifier, char)
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.postEvent(obj, event)
        event = QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyRelease, 0, modifier, char)
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.postEvent(obj, event)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress and isinstance(obj, QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
            print("Normal stroke %d of type %s to %s" % (event.key(), str(event.type()), str(obj)))
            if event.key() in kmap:
                self.sendkeys(obj, "c")
                return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```